# Getting partial responses through WSO2 DSS

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have setup WSO2 DSS 3.1.1 and have connected with an Oracle database. The service is setup well and working fine. Now what I want to try out is to see whether I can get the service to send partial json responses i.e. I can specify as a parameter in the service request what are the columns on the response I want and the service would return me those columns.

e.g. If i request for columns a,b,c then then the service would return me a,b,c columns and if I request for d,e,f columns it would send me only those columns.

1. Is this possible using WSO2 DSS or even ESB?
2. If yes how can it be established?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try number of approaches.

1. Have two different data services for both cases and at ESB, route the request to correct service. That is, based on request call relavat dataservice.
2. You can filter out your [return results](https://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS321/Filtering+Content+to+Specific+User+Roles) based on the roles.
3. You can do change at dataservice. That is, define a stored procedure, where identify the input parameters and based on that return specific columns.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yup any of these three methods could be used for this. Yet I was looking rather at the following method I used. in the query I used SELECT ? FROM table_name and then defined a input parameter which would basically take in the SELECT string I want. After I defined this in resource as well and got this working.

Comment: There seems to be a issue with this when we use json conversion (Header Accept: application/json) is there are special characters. It throws the following error. {"Fault":{"faultcode":"soapenv:Server","faultstring":"Error while writing to the output stream using JsonWriter","detail":""}}. Any work around for this? Thanks again for the help.